# Where is the solenoid coil in my electric shower?

Tags: shower

I am trying to resolve an issue with low water pressure (when dial is turned up to warm temperatures) which I've been told can sometimes be fixed by replacing old/broken solenoid coils. Many guides online tout about how easy it is to do this, but unfortunately I can't seem to find it in mine!

Can anyone point out where the solenoid coil is? I'm wondering if it's sitting above the stabiliser valve (encased in white plastic)...

This is the schematic of my shower: https://www.showerdoc.com/triton-hawaii-2-2011-shower-spares

And below is a picture of shower in question!

[image: My shower - Triton Hawaii 2]

Comment: What country is this unit in?

Comment: It’s in England! :)

Comment: What is the electrical component at the outflow below the heating coil (has two blue and one gnd wire attached)? We have a bottom-of-the-line Bosch gas fired tankless water heater in which the temperature control is seemingly a variable restriction of the flow, so higher temperature output is achieved by reducing the flow rate so a longer residence time in the heating coils, although there is a separate adjustment for the size of the NG flame. What would a solenoid do in these electric flow through heaters? Would a solenoid actuated valve be an over-temperature (safety) shut off?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see all your power is going to the heater with just a safety switch to keep it from getting two hot no solenoid I think one of the 2 things on the right side is a pressure/ flow switch but it has been several years since I worked on my unit, I have a similar unit in my barn and if I try to get the water two warm it barely runs this is the limitation of these small 30 amp units. I adjust the flow to my unit in the winter because the water delivered to the unit is colder and to keep the water warm enough to bathe horses I have to reduce the flow and mixing percentages. In short you may not have a solenoid controlling the water but just a pressure/ flow switch to turn the power on to the small heat tank when there is demand. The stabilizer in your model is more of a tempature regulator not a solenoid , measure the water temp output is it aproxametly at the set point? If so it is working correctly these units do have a limited heating range.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I was under the impression that most modern electric showers have solenoid coils...!

Comment: Well this looks very similar to my unit, and from the photo I do not see an electronic modulation valve or solenoid. My unit only senses pressure & flow to turn on the heater there is no temp control other than how the water is mixed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think you are right.  I think it's that little white piece above the stab.  In all the models I see, it is right next to the stabilizer.

Comment: I thought that too, but it's not. The size is completely different (I have bought a new solenoid coil and it's not the same at all).

Comment: it's also got more than two wires connecting to it (there's a third, green/yellow wire if you look closely!)

Comment: The green/yellow is the ground , the blue brown is the 240 v my unit requires 30 amp breaker yours looks similar.